# Heroku Postgres Julia Support

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm just getting started with Heroku and was reading the documentation. For Heroku Postgres, the list of supported languages does not include Julia. Is there any way that Julia could integrate with Heroku Postgres?

Comment: You can create your own custom buildpack. Example of a custom buildpack: https://github.com/nntin/heroku-buildpack-calibre Example of a project using the custom buildpack: https://github.com/dipu-bd/lightnovel-crawler/blob/master/app.json Read more about it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/buildpacks

Comment: I just noticed there are plenty of Julia buildpacks. https://github.com/Optomatica/heroku-buildpack-julia https://github.com/joshday/heroku-buildpack-julia https://github.com/floored/heroku-buildpack-julia https://github.com/codeneomatrix/heroku-buildpack-julia I'm not too familiar with Julia so you have to pick it on your own or create your own